# High availability periodic task (cron) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

What is the recommend way/pattern for setting up a High Availability (multiple Availability Zones) periodic task (probably triggered using Cron) on AWS?

I would like to have the software installed on multiple EC2 instances in multiple Availability Zones but only have the task run on a single instance at a time. It doesn't matter which instance.

Before moving to AWS, we used to use database locking in a MySQL instance - only the instance that successfully creates a lock would run.

But there must be a better way on AWS? Particularly if there is no requirement for a database.

Thanks!

nick.

Comment: How often does the task run, and how long does it take?

Comment: Did you check Simple WorkFlow (SWF - http://aws.amazon.com/swf/)?

Comment: Don't think SWF has a mechanism for scheduling tasks? (pretty it is the client that has to do the scheduling)

Comment: I would like to run the task hourly and I expect it to take around 10 minutes to run - it is parsing an RSS feed, processing content and then posting content to a third party API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I first asked this question, it is now possible to use CloudWatch Events to schedule periodic events. Events can be:

- A fixed rate of *N* minutes/hours/days
- Cron expression

The targets can be:

- An AWS Lambda function
- Post to an SNS topic
- Write to an SQS queue
- Write to a Kinesis stream
- Perform an action on EC2/EBS instance

SQS could then be used to notify a single instance in a cluster of machines in multiple availability zones to perform an action.

There is more information here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ScheduledEvents.html

Although it does not include a resilience/availability statement of what happens if an Availability Zone goes down.

Answer (score 0):

One suggested solution that has been suggested to me is to use an Auto Scaling Group, with the maximum and minimum number of instances set to 1. This means that if an availability zone goes offline, the ASG will cause a new instance in another zone to be launched.

This technique was briefly covered on the [Architecting on AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/training/course-descriptions/architect/) training course, but I don't know how reliable it is.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon just released the solution to your problem: Beanstalk worker tier periodic tasks:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks

It basically relies on a yaml file listing cron schedules calling the API you want:

> To invoke periodic tasks, your application source bundle must include a cron.yaml file at the root level. The file must contain information about the periodic tasks you want to schedule. Specify this information using standard crontab syntax.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on your requirements.

You could post your tasks to a SQS queue and have your instances (possibly an autoscaling group spread across different zones) poll that queue. SQS' *at least (and generally only) once* semantics could be a problem here if it is critical for you that tasks get executed only once. If that's the case, you could easily use a DynamoDB table and [conditional writes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithDDItems.html#WorkingWithItemsConditionalUpdate). Or, if you're more after a full-fledged fault-tolerant solution, you might give [airbnb chronos](http://airbnb.github.io/chronos/) a try.

Comment: How do you ensure that the system posting tasks on to the SQS queue is highly available?

Comment: SQS is already as highly available as it gets, so if tasks are somehow created by users (or by some other system/component) you can just talk directly to it. In other cases, some sort of event should trigger task creation; again there are a lot of options and designs, but for example you could use CloudWatch (possibly custom metrics) and SNS topics pushing to the queue